How do conductors actually work in electrostatics?
I am mainly confused because we are learning about conductors in electrostatics, and I always think of an electric wire connected to a phone charging it (a phone charger). So, when I hear "conductor," I think of a dynamic state, where a power source provides energy to free the electrons from their energy orbit. Since there is a force applied to free those electrons, an electric field is produced. The electrons move inside the wire, and the ions would slow their speed inside the wire, generating heat as well as charging the phone.
Now, when I try to think of a static state, I try to switch the example by unplugging the wire from the power source. And here I start to get confused: the ions are now stable, and the electrons should stop moving since there is no power source. The energy they have was transmitted to the phone or lost as heat, and after a bit it cools down and we have a charger in astable state,
when the action of unplugging the charger  was done the atoms  would be ionised and electrons sit on the surface ,if it was not plugged to begin with then the electrons are in the outer orbit  ,me coming to a room and seeing a disconnected charger both cases look the same to me, does not this imply me missing something here?
edit
I deleted a paragraph though it was vital , I think with the resources I read and the comments written ,I maybe able to clear up what kind of phenomenon I am struggling with understanding,
I now get that the phone + charger are a closed system , when the charge is connected to the power source it gives energy to free electrons the electrons start flowing and the ions stay in place we have a dipole if I am not wrong and when I connect the charger to the phone it allows electrons to transfer w=to the naturally charged phone and then the charges flow and charge the battery at a certain point when I unplug the charger the system if I understand the battery is like a capacitor so any excess charge in the phone would be there while the excess negative charge in the conductor would stay on the surface because , the thing I am trying to understand is does not the wire stop being polarised at some point,so mainly conduction and polarisation are what puzzling me

"So, when I hear "conductor," I think of a dynamic state". Think of a conductor as something that has the potential to allow the movement of electrical charge.

It is not clear what you mean. The wire is neutral and the electrons are delocalized. Without any external field the charge density is zero everywhere. What happened previously is irrelevant.

"And here I start to get confused: the ions are now stable, and the
electrons should stop moving". The collective motion of the electrons ceases. But the random, thermally caused motion doesn't stop. It exists before and after the presence of the electric field.

@VincentThacker exactly that , since I know what happened before is irrelevant , I don't really understand what to expect from the electrons should I expect them to return to the atoms but that needs energy should I expect them to set on the surfaces of the conductors is achive  a state of equilibrium

@BobD  i see  a material with the  potential to allow movement is a conductor  this helps in changing the thought process from I must think of a dynamic state to it can be in a dynamic state

@BobD " But the random, thermally caused motion doesn't stop. It exists before and after the presence of the electric field", if you can elaborate on this a bit I would be thankful, I understand that for example the wire heats up and when I unplug the cable it is still hot and it will take time to cool down ,but what happens to the electrons is somewhat vague to me , like I feel that at some point the wire stops being charged with the electrons

My point is if it was not a conductor the motions of the electrons would be restricted to the individual atoms. But the conductor allows the electrons to randomly move among all the atoms which is why they call them "mobile charge carriers" in conductors. The protons, on the other hand, are fixed in a solid material, conductor or not. The higher the temperature the greater the random motion. I don't understand what you mean by "the wire stops being charged with electrons".

@BobD this helped clear a lot of things , as for what i mean by that is if i think of a balloon for example that got charged because of me rubbing it gets charged right?

and i can stick it on a board before it falls

When it falls is not that when it stops being charged with a negative or positive charge, so what happens to the electrons on the surface then , something along this

searching it seems like the term is polarised

@dareen The electrons here are delocalized. What matters is the charge density. If the conductor has a net charge density and is isolated, provided it is 3D, the net charge will go to the surface. If the abovementioned conditions do not hold then it is not always true.

@VincentThacker thank you a lot , I certainly did not understand the concept of delocalisation neither  connected this to charge density distribution  , I can't say I fully understand this now but it feels like the missing peace that I needed ,and it is clearing things up I will go read about this

@dareen yes it gets charged, but a balloon is not a conductor. Electrons move to the balloon due to friction, not conduction. You were asking about conductors.

There are different kinds of conductors. The common thing is charges are free to move around.
Metals are a common example. In a metal, some electrons do not stay in orbitals around individual atoms. Instead they spread out over the solid.
Salt water is another example. Na$^+$ and Cl$^-$ ions drift around freely.
If a conductor is charged, the extra electrons repel each other through their electric fields. They spread out. When the forces of repulsion in all directions are balanced, they stop moving.

is not there a point in time ,where the conductor stops being charged ? or should I do something actively for it to stop

I remember rubbing  q balloon on my hair before and it  getting charged until it falls down again

so do those electrons stay on the surface until I try to actively  discharge it or do the electrons get back to the atoms for some reason , maybe this is the second part I am stuck with

Typically charges can move around freely in a conductor, but they cannot easily leave the conductor. But they often slowly leak away. Something like molecules move around freely in water, but cannot easily leave. Never the less, water slowly evaporates.
